# Load library in a java shebang script

Tags: java, shell, java-11

Since JDK-11 we have ability to run java source code directly. This code

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.Md5Crypt;

public class Oneliner {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(Md5Crypt.md5Crypt("ok".getBytes(), "$1$saltsalt"));
  }
}
```

can be run with

```
$ /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11/bin/java --source 8 -cp /home/imaskar/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.11/commons-codec-1.11.jar jscript.java
```

But in a shell script form (shebang)

```
#!/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11/bin/java --source 8 --class-path /home/imaskar/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.11/commons-codec-1.11.jar

import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.Md5Crypt;

public class Oneliner {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(Md5Crypt.md5Crypt("ok".getBytes(), "$1$saltsalt"));
  }
}
```

I get an error:

```
$ ./jscript.sh
Error: Could not find or load main class ..jscript.sh
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: //jscript/sh
```

The problem is `--class-path` argument in the first line. For some reason `--souce` argument gets through, but `--class-path` doesn't.

Comment: Given the parameter `jscript.sh`, java tries to execute the `sh` class from the `jscript` package, so I think you need to rename your file back to `jscript.java` (this shouldn't prevent shebang interpretation). Moreover, I don't see the directory containing your java file in your `--class-path` argument, which must be a problem.

Comment: @Aaron in jdk-11 they accomodated for that. With `--source` option java knows that this is a source file name.

Comment: thanks for the info, I should have read the JEP. It still looks like in your error that it's trying to load an `sh` class, but I guess that's because the arguments aren't parsed correctly as you said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This **does not generally work** in OpenJDK <= `11.0.7`. Whether this is a bug and gets fixed or not is not clear yet. There is an open bug report:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8242911

Specifying the `--class-path` works at least with OpenJDK `12.0.2` and `14.0.1`.
So I assume some improvements made for Java 12 fixed this issue.

So the line in the question is *supposed* to work, no change needed:

```
#!/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11/bin/java --source 8 --class-path /home/imaskar/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.11/commons-codec-1.11.jar
```

---

Some notes on other things mentioned in the other answer and in the comments:

- `--source` **must be** the first argument. In shebang files, the first line is treated like `#!$COMMAND $ONE-SINGLE-ARGUMENT`. So the shell will not separate the `$ONE-SINGLE-ARGUMENT` by whitespace. Thus, the Java launcher will split the argument by whitespace iff it starts with `--source` and further process the other arguments.
- I can't fully explain muttonUp's working example. I suspect it is related to the usage of macOS. Maybe the used shell split up the shebang argument already.
- Thus, it might be that this issue is limited to certain shells. I have tested the behavior with Ubuntu's `bash` and `dash`.

Comment: Indeed, in MacOS `--source` works first and second for me now (with java 14), which shouldn't be the case according to spec.

Comment: You can get around that stupid shebang parsing by delegating it to env: `#!/bin/env -S java --source 11 --more-arguments`

Answer (score 5):

As told in previous answers there is a bug in java 11:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8242911

I found this work around that let me use the class-path parameter:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S java --class-path /path/mylib.jar --source 11
```

Note the order of the parameters, if `--source` is before `--class-path` it does not work.

Comment: upvoting just because this is how I figured out how to do it with `/usr/bin/env` which is the only way it should be done since there is no way to guarantee where java itself will be installed on any given system. It's not like `sh`, where there should always be one at `/bin/sh` that's guaranteed to be mounted (/usr is not guaranteed to be mounted by FHS) and bourne shell compatible

Comment: I wonder, does --class-path have to be absolute? can you use env ($HOME) or `~`

Answer (score 3):

Your shebang arguments are the wrong way round.

`--class-path` needs to come before `--source`

It is mentioned [in the original JEP](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330), but it rather esoteric, and split across a couple of sections...

The below will work.

```
#!/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11/bin/java --class-path /home/imaskar/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.11/commons-codec-1.11.jar --source 8 

import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.Md5Crypt;

public class Oneliner {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(Md5Crypt.md5Crypt("ok".getBytes(), "$1$saltsalt"));
  }
}
```

My Version is below

```
$ /usr/bin/java -version
java version "11" 2018-09-25
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11+28)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11+28, mixed mode)

$ cat kkkk.sh
#!/usr/bin/java --class-path /Users/steven/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.11/commons-codec-1.11.jar --source 8

import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.Md5Crypt;

public class Oneliner {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(Md5Crypt.md5Crypt("ok".getBytes(), "$1$saltsalt"));
    }
}

$ ./kkkk.sh
$1$saltsalt$PXysoX71YwjJOoKzgzTEg/
```

Note: When this answer was written (JDK 11 ea) the `--class-path` parameter needed to be before the `--source` as per my example. Now (JDK 15) the order of the parameters does not matter and either order will work.

Comment: ```Unrecognized option: --class-path /home/imaskar/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.11/commons-codec-1.11.ja
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.```

Comment: @Imaskar make sure you haven't any weird chars with `cat -A` maybe?

Comment: @Aaron no, nothing unusual. Btw, thanks for the interesting command.

Comment: @Imaskar type in the classpath, yours should end in `.jar` not `.ja`

Comment: @muttonUp it would be too obvious. classpath is okay, just the error message is cut.

Comment: This is the line I use, which works with your code `#!/usr/bin/java --class-path /Users/steven/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.11/commons-codec-1.11.jar --source 8`

Comment: @muttonUp can you please show your `/usr/bin/java -version`?

Comment: I've added it to 'my version'. However yesterday when I originally wrote it was ea-27, it's now ea-28, but both worked.

Comment: And what OS? I tested on Ubuntu 16.04 and 17.10. I found out that it works via args-file. Still no success with a single script.

Comment: I'm using MacOS. Could this be the issue - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037646/why-is-openjdk-10-packaged-as-openjdk-11

Comment: This answer is wrong, `--source` needs to be first.